# How can I yield multiple values in a jest test of redux-saga

Tags: react-native, generator, jestjs, redux-saga

I'm just getting started on writing tests using Jest for my React Native project that uses redux-sagas and generator functions. I don't have a lot of experience with tests, so please forgive my ignorance if this is something basic.

I have the following function, which defines variables based on yielding results from another function. I can't figure out how to mock multiple variables...

## My function

```
export function * getAssets (api) {
  const bearerToken = yield select(selectBearerToken)
  const timelines = yield select(selectTimelines)

  if (timelines) {
    // Do stuff with timelines
    const response = yield call(api.getAssetById, bearerToken, 'abc123')
  }
}
```

## My test

```
const stepper = (fn) => (mock) => fn.next(mock).value

test('getAssets', () => {
  const step = stepper(getAssets(FixtureAPI))
  const bearerToken = 'bearer_test_token'
  const timelines = 'mocked for brevity'

  expect(step()).toEqual(select(selectBearerToken))
  expect(step()).toEqual(select(selectTimelines))
  expect(step(timelines)).toEqual(call(FixtureAPI.getAssetById(bearerToken, 'B13fGCE_l')))
})
```

## The problem

When it calls `getAssetById`, `bearerToken` is undefined, but `timelines` is defined; because I passed it into `step()`. How can I pass both `timelines` and `bearerToken` into `step()`? Is that even how I'd do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can spend some time reading about JavaScript Generators here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators, especially the advanced generators part.

Long story short, `yield` will return the value of the evaluation of the expression following the `yield` keyword for the `next` call. In this case, when you call `step()` for the first time, the return value should be what `select(selectBearerToken)` evaluates to. `next` can also takes in a value, i.e. `.next(val)`, which will be passed back to as the return value of the `yield` call. That is way when you call `step()` the third time with `timelines`, it first pass back `timelines` to the previous `yield` call and then it goes on to the next `yield` and stops and returns.

The way you want to correctly test this is for your second `step()` call, also pass back a value for `bearerToken`, i.e. `expect(step(bearerToken)).toEqual(select(selectTimelines))`. Then, the bearerToken should be set.

One suggestion is to separate the `step()` call with your assertions to make it easier to understand IMO.

Comment: Thank you. I was mistaken, thinking that passing a result into a previous `step()` would not be available later.